# PHP: filtering mysql_query result for specific column?

Tags: php, mysql, filter

Is there a quick way to filter a mysql_query result to get a list containing only values of a specific column?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$list_of_user_names = get_values($query,"names");
```

What is the name of the function to be used in place of `get_values`?

Comment: `SELECT names FROM users` and then fetch the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your field name in databse is "names"

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM users");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['names'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**NOTE : mysql_* functions are deprecated in new version of php, use mysqli_* or PDO**

Answer (score 0):

Use below function.

```
  function get_values($q,$c)
  {
       $arr = array();
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
       {
            $arr[] = $row[$c];
       }
       return $arr; // return all names value.
  }
```

Comment: No, I mean... thank you, this does answer the question, but I'm looking for an official implementation (or something that could be used on it's place, such as a filter function).

Comment: @Dokkat You have to iterate the mysql result to obtain the result. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM users");

if (!$query) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $names

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row["names"];

}
```